# How to automatically enable a visual Force tab to show on Salesforce1 mobile apps

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, tab

The App I am working on has a Visual Force tab , which I would like it to show automatically on salesforce1.
Currently the tab would show only when I go to Setup > Mobille Administration > Manage Mobile Navigation Menu and then select the app's tab into the selected list.

I have also tried setting the tab's meta.xml file with these two options
  true
  false

but doesn't seem to take into effect! Is there was of making this tab available without having to set it up manually?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable Visualforce pages for Salesforce1 through the metadata API by editing the `isAvailableInTouch` field on the `ApexPage` object.

Read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_visualforce.htm&language=en_US)

Comment: This is what I have tried already and it doesn't seem to show the tab still

Comment: when i try using the isAvailableInTouch I get an error Description Save error: Error parsing file: Element {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}isAvailableInTouch invalid at this location in type ApexPage myApp.page-meta.xml /myAppSales Force/src/pages line 4 Force.com save problem